# Only show date by removing time part from date and time in webgrid.column

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I have a webgrid column which returns date and time as ex: "11/29/2013 2:49:56 PM" . I dont want to change my SP but want to show only date in column as "11/29/2013". How is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model have a datetime item say 'CreatedDate' and you are binding this item with your webgrid column then you can use the below code to format datetime

```
@item.CreatedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyy")
```

Comment: Wow !Great one liner!Saved a lot of time,Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If your model doest not have Datetime means use this

DateTime CreatedDate= Convert.ToDateTime(@item.CreatedDate);

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the ans.. but its not what i meant. I already have the value,I just had to trim it to show only date. The ans i have ticked works fine . :)